# loading JSON data from angular service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Please forgive me if this is a simply problem for an angular guru, i am fairly new to services.

Below is a snippet of my controller where i have attempted make a service request to call out data from my JSON file "jobs.json".

I am not receiving an data when i load my web page neither i am seeing the JSON file in inspector element.

I assume there's something incorrect in my below code. Does anyone what the issue is?
[Click here if you need to play about with the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
"use strict"; 

var app = angular.module("tickrApp", []);

app.service("tickrService", function ($http, $q){
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('app/data/items.json').then(function (data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
});

this.getItems = function () {
    return deferred.promise;
}
  })

 .controller('tickCtrl', function($scope, tickrService) {

var promise = tickrService.getItems();
promise.then(function (data){

    $scope.items= getData;
    console.log($scope.items);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Plunkr, you had a few errors, such as the `<script>` tags around the wrong way (you need to have Angular first, so your code can then use `angular.module`). You also had the wrong attribute of `ng-app-data` instead of `data-ng-app`.

The key problem was with the JS code, the first parameter to the success handler for the `$http.get()` call is an object with a `data` property, which is the actual data returned. So you should resolve your promise with that property instead.

Then in the controller, like Michael P. said, `getData` is undefined, you should use the `data` parameter passed in.

```
app.service("tickrService", function($http, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('jobs.json').then(function(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
  });

  this.getjobs = function() {
    return deferred.promise;
  }
})

.controller('tickCtrl', function($scope, tickrService) {

  var promise = tickrService.getjobs();
  promise.then(function(data) {

    $scope.jobs = data;
    console.log($scope.jobs);
  });

});
```

See [forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/crbYzhhynCwHmYsGrTjc?p=preview).

Comment: Beat me to it, I was just typing out the same thing. Here have an upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

In the success handler of your `getItems` function, you are storing `getData`, which is *undefined*. You want to store `data` instead.

Therefore, in the controller, your call to `getItems()` should be as follows

```
tickrService.getItems().then(function (data) {
    $scope.items = data;
});
```

Also, you want to make the $http call in `getItems`. Like that :

```
this.getItems = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('app/data/items.json').then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**However**, you can avoid the above boilerplate code around the promises, because `$http.get` returns itself a promise. Your service and controller could be much more concise and less polluted by boilerplate code.

**The service could be as simple as :**

```
app.service("tickrService", function ($http) {

    this.getItems = function () {
        return $http.get('app/data/items.json');
    }
});
```

**And the controller could be shortened to:**

```
app.controller('tickCtrl', function ($scope, tickrService) {

    tickrService.getItems().then(function (response) {
        $scope.items = response.data;
    })
});
```

Please note that the response resolved by `$http` is an object that contains [(link to doc)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

- `data` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- `status` – HTTP status code of the response.
- `headers` – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- `config` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- `statusText` – HTTP status text of the response.

Therefore in the success handler of `getItems` we are storing `response.data`, which is the response body, and not the whole response object.